# Был ли у Вас конфликт Events Calendar и LearnPress?

Tags: wordpress

Возникла проблема. Обновил плагин Events Calendar и LearnPress до последних, и теперь невозможно добавить, удалить или отредактировать виджеты.  Сама ошибка якобы в файле Events Calendar, НО, если отключить LearnPress, все работает хорошо. Наоборот также. 
Скриншот ошибки: https://www.screencast.com/t/rqNQtorchc

Кто-то сталкивался с таким?

P.S.: На дефолтной теме (TwentySeventeen) все также, то есть это не проблема в моей теме.

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно было разрегистрировать скрипты плагинов и добавить актуальную версию для админки.

https://geek-code.ru/oshibka-select2-v-wordpress.html